# How can I use the output of intermediate layer of one model as input to another model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I train a model `A` and try to use the output of the intermediate layer with the `name="layer_x"` as an additional input for model `B`.

I tried to use the output of the intermediate layer like on the Keras doc 
https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer.

Model A:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(100,))
dnn = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
dnn = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="layer_x")(dnn)
dnn = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dnn)
output = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dnn)
```

Model B:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(200,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(100,)) # input for model A

# loading model A
model_a = keras.models.load_model(path_to_saved_model_a)

intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model_a.input, 
                                 outputs=model_a.get_layer("layer_x").output)

intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)

merge_layer = concatenate([input_1, intermediate_output])
dnn_layer = Dense(512, activation="relu")(merge_layer)
output = Dense(5, activation="sigmoid")(dnn_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
```

When I debug I get an error on this line:

```
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model_a.input, 
                                 outputs=model_a.get_layer("layer_x").output)

File "..", line 89, in set_model
  outputs=self.neural_net_asc.model.get_layer("layer_x").output)
File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\WinPython\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 1592, in __init__
  mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

I can access the tensor with `get_layer("layer_x").output` and the `output_mask` is `None`. Do I have to set manually an output mask and how do I set up this output mask if needed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two things that you seem to be doing wrong :

```
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

when you do `.predict()`, you are actually passing data through the graph and asking what will be the result. When you do that, `intermediate_output` will be a numpy array and not a layer as you would like it to be.

Secondly, you don't need to recreate a new intermediate model. You can directly use the part of `model_a` that interest you.

Here is a code that "compiles" for me :

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(100,))
dnn = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
dnn = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="layer_x")(dnn)
dnn = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dnn)
output = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dnn)

model_a = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

# You don't need to recreate an input for the model_a, 
# it already has one and you can reuse it
input_b = Input(shape=(200,))

# Here you get the layer that interests you from model_a, 
# it is still linked to its input layer, you just need to remember it for later
intermediate_from_a = model_a.get_layer("layer_x").output

# Since intermediate_from_a is a layer, you can concatenate it with the other input
merge_layer = concatenate([input_b, intermediate_from_a])
dnn_layer = Dense(512, activation="relu")(merge_layer)
output_b = Dense(5, activation="sigmoid")(dnn_layer)
# Here you remember that one input is input_b and the other one is from model_a
model_b = Model(inputs=[input_b, model_a.input], outputs=output_b)
```

I hope this is what you wanted to do.

Please tell me if something isn't clear :-)

Comment: hey I finally found my mistake I used tensorflow.python.keras api and here I imported from keras.models and the 2 different keras versions of tensorflow and pure keras could not work together :) but thank you for your answer but also I do not use the predict method now

Comment: @Nassim which is the proper way of train such a "chain-of-models"?

Comment: It really depends on the case... The natural way seems to be 1) train model A, 2) freeze common layers, 3) train model B with frozen layers from model A

Comment: @NassimBen I see, I was hoping in some keras (tensorflow) magic to do the training one shot...

Comment: That kind of model is really application specific... the way you train it really depends on the reasons why those two models are connected... so no magic to my knowledge :D sorry