# How to get hidden state matrices out of stacked BiLSTM layer in Tensorflow Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to write code for this architecture (Question Answering model: Paper https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cin/2019/9543490/) and looking for help how to get hidden state matrices Hq and Ha from stacked BiLSTM layers. Could some one please advise.

[image]

[image]

```
# Creating Embedding Layer for Query
# Considered fixed length as 40 for both question and answer as per research paper
embedding_layer1 = layers.Embedding(vocab_size_query, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix_query], input_length =40, trainable=False)
input_text1 =Input(shape=(40,), name="input_text")
x = embedding_layer1(input_text1)

# Creating Bidirectional layer for Query
# Each word in the context and question should be made aware of the nearby words occurring. We use a bi-directional recurrent neural network (LSTM’s) here.
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128,recurrent_dropout=0.5,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True))(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128,recurrent_dropout=0.5,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True))(x)
flatten_1 = Flatten()(x)

## Creating Embedding Layer for Passage
embedding_layer2 = layers.Embedding(vocab_size_answer, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix_answer], input_length =40, trainable=False)
input_text2 =Input(shape=(40,), name="input_text")
x2 = embedding_layer2(input_text2)

# Creating Bidirectional layer for Passage
x2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128,recurrent_dropout=0.5,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True))(x2)
x2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128,recurrent_dropout=0.5,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True))(x2)
flatten_2 = Flatten()(x2)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the output of intermediate layer of one model as input to another model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846332/how-can-i-use-the-output-of-intermediate-layer-of-one-model-as-input-to-another)

Comment: Thanks @Minh-TuanNguyen but my question is different. How to get the hidden state matrix from Bidirectional LSTM layer. If we get this for left part of the above architecture(question sequence), I can apply the same for right part(answer sequence).

Comment: If I think correctly then the output that you want to obtain is flatten 1 and flatten 2, because these are the output of the stacked BDLSTM, is that correct?

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen Yes, I just want to understand the output which I am getting from flatten_1 and flatten_2 - Are they hidden state matrices Hq and Ha which the model architecture is expecting. 

Shape of flatten_1:
`<tf.Tensor 'bidirectional_1/Identity:0' shape=(None, 40, 256) dtype=float32>`

Shape of flatten_2: 
`<tf.Tensor 'bidirectional_3/Identity:0' shape=(None, 40, 256) dtype=float32>`

Comment: Thank you @Minh-TuanNguyen. That is correct. Those are the matrices I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the model structure and your source code, you can obtain the Hq and Ha by extracting the output of flatten_1 and flatten_2 layer. To extract the output of an intermediate layer, you can create a new model with input as the original input, and the output as the appropriate layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

model = ...  # create the original model

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```